Is there a way to derive the Polar Curve Area Formula using Parametrics?
I just finished up Calc BC, and one formula that my teacher never really went into the derivation of was how the area of a polar curve is given by $A=\frac12\int_\alpha^\beta r^2d\theta$.
One that I do understand, at the very least on a conceptual level, is area for a parametric curve, given by $A=\int_a^by(t)x'(t)dt$.
But we also learned that we can essentially represent polar curves as parametric equations using the identities $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.
Is it possible to derive the former equation for polar functions by plugging these expressions for $x$ and $y$ into the integral? I briefly tried it myself, by got stuck after taking the derivative of $x$ with respect to $\theta$, as that becomes $\frac{dx}{d\theta}=\cos\theta\frac{dr}{d\theta}-r\sin\theta$, and I'm not sure how to deal with the $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ in the integrand.

Welcome to MSE! <> Offhand I'd try integrating by parts, but alternatively, the area integrand $\frac{1}{2}(y, dx - x, dy)$ immediately gives the desired formula. If you're happy with that please feel free to type up your own answer!

The mapping of the Cartesian to Polar coordinates is $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$.
The transformation of areas is
$$
\int\int dx dy = \int\int ||\begin{array}{cc}
\partial x/ \partial r & \partial x/ \partial \theta\\
\partial y/ \partial r & \partial y/ \partial \theta\\
\end{array}||dr d\theta
$$
where the double vertical bars are the absolute value of the jacobian determinant of
the partial derivatives:
$$
||\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta & -r\sin \theta\\
\sin\theta & r\cos\theta\\
\end{array}||
=
r.
$$
Then the assumption is that the area stretches from the origin up to the point where the radius is set,
and the $r$-integral is performed as $\int r dr = \frac12 r^2$ and the $\theta$-integral is left over.

Does Jacobian matrix have to be used because we are changing the coordinate system we are working in? I'm not too familiar with much of the multivariable calculus/linear algebra stuff.

There are math genius that would have guessed right away the factor $r^2/2$ because this is the area proportional to the full circle area $\pi r^2$ for $\theta=2\pi$. Think of the factor $1/2$ as halving
the area of a rectangle of size $\theta \times r$ (the circle sector is like a triangle.) Nothing forces you to use any sort of technique to get anywhere, but as soon as the geometries become complicated (ellipsoidal, higher dimensional) it's worth to recall some basic standard algebra of higher-dimensional integrals. The Jacobian is the higher-dimensional analog of the 1-D substitution rule.
